# Mesh becomes flat when working with Fracture Modifier Branch. Is this a regular bug?

Tags: modifiers, rigid-body-simulation

I'm working on a simulation with the Fracture Modifier Branch. Sometimes my fractured object turns into this flat object and there's no way I can restore this. I tried removing the rigid body world, turning the modifiers on and off, but nothing seems to work. Does anyone know how to fix this issue?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, this looks very odd indeed. Looks like something has been scaled to 0 in one direction accidently. The FM does apply the scaling when fracturing, though.(bullet cannot deal very well with scaled objects, imho).

But without the blend this is all just guessing. Could you share it here maybe, so I can take a look ?